# Анализ кадра с камеры на предмет перевёрнутого изображения

Tags: php, c++, изображения

Есть клиенты на C++, которые транслируют кадры с веб-камер на HTTP-сервер. Некоторые камеры отдают перевёрнутые кадры, и нужно программно анализировать и переворачивать кадр если он перевёрнут.

Знаю, что это можно реализовать при помощи OpenCV, но клиент и так достаточно нагружен и захватом камеры (vfw32), и сетевым обменом, и прочими наворотами, поэтому не очень охота его нагружать дополнительным анализом, ведь у большинства пользователей далеко не самые мощные машины.

**Возможно ли выполнение такого анализа средствами GD в PHP?**

Comment: А нужно ли делать весь этот анализ постоянно? я просто бы сделал галочку "переворачивать картинку для этой камеры" и готово.

Comment: Это уже реализовано средствами CSS/JS, но заказчики хотят автоматизации, чтобы не кликать ))

Comment: Я натыкался на эту проблему и решил ее очень хитро. Я транслировал видео с камер ноутбуков. И там также картинка иногда перевернута. Но оказалось, что в большинстве случаев достаточно знать имя устройства и версию драйверов.

Но не забывайте, что пользователь может просто перевернуть камеру и нужно определиться, в этом случае что делать? И второе - не всегда, даже группа людей может определить, перевернута ли картинка (говорят, квадрат Малевича так провисел вверх ногами и никто не заметил. Доверяй потом этим экспертам).

Comment: Ну версию драйвера то я знаю всегда при инициализации класса камеры - это как правило стандартный Windows драйвер. Конечно сама версия может отличаться. А есть какой-нибудь справочник по этой теме (типа "драйверы и их поведение на определённых устройствах")?

Comment: "Возможно ли выполнение такого анализа средствами GD в PHP?" это может быть тяжолой операций для php, т.к. вам надо раскодировать кадр, чтобы определить. Действительно может быть вам это делать на клиента один раз для камеры, клиенты может быть не заметят коротковренной высокой нагрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть возможность обновить клиент, то можно добавить meta информацию в изображение или 1 пиксель в правом нижнем углу определенного цвета, по которому и можно будет определять реальное положение изображения.
Часто даже человек не может определить правильное положение изображения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы посмотрел отличия meta в изображениях от камеры, которая отдает нормальное изображение от камеры, которая дает перевернутое. Возможно, можно обойтись легким чтением начала файла.

Comment: Необычное, но, на мой взгляд, очень эффективное решение! Надо подумать в каком месте кода эти мета-данные рисовать и всё должно работать. Клиент я сам писал, конечно обновлю ))

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF Так ничего нового придумывать не нужно. PHP может прочитать EXIF http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exif-read-data.php